# How to create material design input form using css and bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4, material-design

I want to design following material design input form using css and bootstrap. Following code is I am currently using. But it doesn't provide exact result I want.

Code Pen Link : [View Source Code Here](https://codepen.io/chrisoncode/pen/IdGKH)

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="container">

  <h2>Google Material Design in CSS3<small>Inputs</small></h2>

  <form>

    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>

  </form>

  <p class="footer">
    a <a href="https://scotch.io/tutorials/css/google-material-design-input-boxes-in-css3" target="_blank">tutorial</a> by <a href="https://scotch.io" target="_blank">scotch.io</a>
  </p>

</div>
```

But I want this design :

[image]

Comment: Hi @BenjaminTreadwell thank you for the reply. Yes I want something like in the image (Form). I have try it using css. But I can't create it. Can you help me. I want to use pure css and bootstrap only.

Comment: Unfortunatly, your question isn't really a question so much as a request to produce code for you - which could be solved through a multitude of different solutions. Therefore, your 'question' is a bit too broad to 'answer', and I believe it's subject to be flagged accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you've tagged Bootstrap 4, I'm assuming you wanted the solution with regards to that framework.

Setup a default form-group, label, and input markup like this;

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="usr">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
</div>
```

Then add this css, what this would do is

1. position label relative to its container (form-group)
2. then we specified the top and left positions so that it would land
   on top of the input field
3. I added a white background and padding to the label so that it would have a box around the label.

```
.form-group > label {
  top: 18px;
  left: 6px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

**Here's a fiddle** with that code on bootstrap 4;
http://jsfiddle.net/rw29jot4/

For the animation, check this fiddle, we need to utilize click events and move the position of the label;

**Updated code with animation;**
http://jsfiddle.net/sedvo037/

### EDIT: Please see my answer below which uses only CSS.

Comment: Hi @Jerdine Sabio. Thank you for the answer. It really helps. But I want some animation to be add. http://angular-material.fusetheme.com/ui/forms. Can You look this form design and suggest a code for this animation.

Comment: @shehan96 I updated the answer, do see the last fiddle link

Comment: Hi @Jerdine Sabio, Thank you very much for the answer. I am now using it. Thanks. But I come up with new small issue. I can't add type="date". How can I do that?

Comment: @shehan96 It's working fine on my end, I just replaced the type on the input to date `<input type="date" />`. Just replace `type=text` to `type=date`

Comment: I tried it. But doesn't work. I think it is because the browser. It's not working on safari.

Comment: @shehan96 I see, if that's the case, you might need to implement a javascript date picker. You could mark this as the answer already and create a new question. Be sure to include the datepicker you want to implement.

Comment: Sure. I'll make another question for that. Thank you very much for the support and answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @shehan96 sure thing, I'll check your new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

CSS Only solution; use combination of sibling selector `~` on the label and `:valid` pseudo selector on the input.

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.form-group>label {
  bottom: 34px;
  left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  transition: 0.2s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form-control:focus~label {
  bottom: 55px;
}

.form-control:valid~label {
  bottom: 55px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <br>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" required>
        <label for="usr">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" required>
        <label for="usr">Password</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code.

HTML:

```
  <div class="main_div">
  <div class="group">
      <input type="text" required="required"/>
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main_div{
    padding: 30px;
}
input,
textarea {
    background: none;
    color: #c6c6c6;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 320px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}
input:hover{
    border: 3px solid black;
}
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label,
textarea:valid ~ label {
    top: -5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    left: 11px;
}
input:focus ~ .bar:before,
textarea:focus ~ .bar:before {
    width: 320px;
}

input[type="password"] {
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}
.group{
    position: relative;
}
label {
    color: #c6c6c6;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 15px;
    top: 12px;
    transition: 300ms ease all;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Swati. Thank you for the answer. It really helps. But I want some animation to be add. angular-material.fusetheme.com/ui/forms. Can You look this form design and suggest a code for this animation